# How to add a key in a mongo document on the basis of an existing key?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a document as follows:

```json
{
    "_id": "1234",
    "created_at": 1678787680
}
```

I want to modify the document and add a new key `updated_at` which will be a datetime equivalent of the `created_at` UNIX timestamp.

```json
{
    "_id": "1234",
    "created_at": 1678787680,
    "updated_at": "2023-03-14 15:39:18.767232"
}
```

Is there a way to perform this operation using `updateMany`?

Comment: Have you tried `$$NOW`?

Comment: Will it not give me current timestamp?

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted?  You can then modify it using $convert, $toLong, or any of the date operators.

Comment: I want to add a new key updated_at which will be of type ISODate and this updated_at key will get its value from created_at key which is a UNIX timestamp and is currently present in the document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$toDate`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/). You are better off storing dates as proper BSON date types  (not as strings in your example).

mongosh:

```
db.mycollection.updateMany({}, [{'$set': {'updated_at': {'$toDate': {'$multiply': ['$created_at', 1000]}}}}])
```

pymongo:

```
db.mycollection.update_many({}, [{'$set': {'updated_at': {'$toDate': {'$multiply': ['$created_at', 1000]}}}}])
```

full example:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']


db.mycollection.insert_one({
    "_id": "1234",
    "created_at": 1678787680
})

db.mycollection.update_many({}, [{'$set': {'updated_at': {'$toDate': {'$multiply': ['$created_at', 1000]}}}}])
print(db.mycollection.find_one())
```

prints:

```
{'_id': '1234', 'created_at': 1678787680, 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 14, 9, 54, 40)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { updated_at: { $toDate: { $multiply: ["$created_at", 1000] } } } }
])
```